# Magento: category menu bar

Tags: magento, menu, categories

With limited knowledge of Magento, I like to ask about top menu for Magento.

I have catergory menu like this in my example site.
[example of top category menu bar in magento based site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DTgP.png)

How can I change to like this?
[Amazon dropdown menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfeas.png)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for you is to look-up some Magento themes that have the vertical menu or you can use a vertical navigation plugin from [Magento Connect](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=vertical%20menu&pl=0).